# Second derivative of Kahler potential

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity

Does the following second covariant (in terms of Kahler geometry) derivative of Kahler potential vanish?
\begin{equation}
K_{ij}\equiv\nabla_i\nabla_j K=0,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
K_{i^*j^*}\equiv\nabla_{i^*}\nabla_{j^*} K=0?
\end{equation}
Indices represent complex coordinates ($A_i$ and $\bar{A}_i$) on Kahler manifold.

I need this to show that
\begin{equation}
K_i\Box A_i=-K_{ij^*}\partial^m A_i\partial_m\bar{A}_j+\text{total derivative},
\end{equation}
where partial derivatives and the box operator are taken WRT space-time coordinates (for which $A$ and $\bar{A}$ are scalar fields, of course).

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1831715/11127

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was crossposted.